# Select polygons intersecting (or completely within) another polygon [R sf]

Tags: r, intersection, r-sf

I would like to select polygons from one simple feature collection that intersect a polygon in another sf collection. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc <- st_transform(nc,32717);nc
poly <- nc[1,]
fishnet<-st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(poly)),cellsize=5000)
```

Now, having created poly and a fishnet around it, I would like to select those fishnet cells that intersect poly or that are completely contained by poly.

Thanks for any help!

Mark

Comment: Have you tried using  `sf::st_intersection()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fishnet2 <- fishnet[poly,]
```

And a plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = poly, fill = "blue") +
  geom_sf(data = fishnet2, color = "red", fill = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Eugene, this works really well, thanks for your help!

Comment: When I run this exact code I get an error: "> fishnet2 <- fishnet[poly,]
Error in `[.default`(fishnet, poly, ) : incorrect number of dimensions".

I've used this workflow in other places, I'm surprised to run into this error with the fishnet. Any insights?

Comment: not sure what changed in sf, but if you wrap the `fishnet` in `st_as_sf()`, my answer will work again. So do `fishnet<-st_as_sf(st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(poly)),cellsize=5000))` and then my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update @EugeneChong! Also, @Mark - this question and answer is a great example of making a grid like this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171710/create-a-grid-inside-a-shapefile . I would argue it might be a better example of creating a grid than the answer given there. Could be good to add to your explanation for future users!